# Posted Variable Not being Sent to Db - Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, variables

I have a `Codeigniter Form`:

```
<?php
    $attr = array('id'=>'urlSubmit','method'=>'post');
    $urlInputAttr = array('name'=>'urlInput','value'=>'yourdomain.com','maxlength'=>'50','size'=>'25');
    echo form_open('urlSubmission',$attr);
    echo form_input($urlInputAttr);
    echo form_close();
?>
```

then a `controller`:

```
 $this->load->view('support/header', $urlSubmissionMeta); ## Header info 
  $this->load->view('support/toolbar'); #logo
  //
    # Determine whether domain already has been crawled.
    $this->load->model('domaincheckmodel');
        $this->domaincheckmodel->verifyduplicates(); 

    # Then Perform Scan
    $this->load->model('performscanmodel');
        $this->performscanmodel->fetchlinks();
```

A `model`, called domaincheckmodel.php:

```
   function verifyduplicates(){
        #PREPARE DATA
        $postedTLD = $_POST["urlInput"];    // Get unsanitized data
        $sql = "SELECT tld from ClientDomain WHERE tld = ?";
        $endquery = $this->db->query($sql,array($this->db->escape_str($postedTLD))); // Query db

        #CONDITION   - if #rows GT 0, load domain already exists.
        if($endquery->num_rows() > 0){
            $this->load->view('err/domainexists'); ##domain already used
            ## redir to new pagee to .. please login..
        } 

        else{ #number of rows must be 0, insert into db
            $newDomain = "INSERT INTO ClientDomain(tld) VALUES('".$this->db->escape_str($postedTLD)."')";
            $this->db->query($newDomain);

            $this->load->view('success/domainfree');
            ## please register to begin saving history of your scans, without doing so you lose results.
        }
```

The problem is when I submit the form, the `if{}` and `else{}` statements work fine in the model, but the variable `$postedTLD` is sending a blank value to mysql.

Any thoughts here why this is being sent?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$postedTLD = $_POST["urlInput"];
```

should be:

```
$postedTLD = $this->input->post('urlInput');
```

See the [documentation](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/input.html#content) for more info on how to access POST values.

Comment: although this answer is right, I recommend reading this answer relating to best programming practices. [SO Question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4096728/1260593)

Comment: What's the difference between the two?

Comment: details how the view is tied to the model, as opposed to the controller.

Answer (score 0):

You can get all post data  as array by using a single line code.

```
$postData=$this->input->post(NULL,TRUE);
```